# Finding the probability with an uneven dice

Tags: probability, dice

A dice is weighted such that the **chance** to throw a certain eye *(1,2,3,4,5 or 6)* is proportional with this eye.

If I understand this correctly, that would mean if I throw a *5* ; then the chances to have thrown a *5* are *1,5,10* etc. How would I go about expressing the probability of throwing this *5* (i am confused..).

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by 'chances are 1,5,10'. Just add all the probabilities and you should get 1, so solve for the common ratio $r$ such that $P(X=i)=ir$, then you can get all your probabilities.

Comment: The sum of the probabilities is supposed to be one. So you divide the numbers by the sum of the eyes. Let denote $p_i$ as the probability to roll number $i$ once. Then the formula is

$p_i=\frac{i}{1+2+3+4+5+6}=\frac{i}{21} \ \forall \ 1\leq i\leq 6$

Comment: @aNumosh ah ok, they all add up to 21, so the chances of throwing a 5 would be 5/21 , i get it i was having brain faurt

Answer (score 2):

It means that $p_{1}:p_{2}:p_{3}:p_{4}:p_{5}:p_{6}=1:2:3:4:5:6$ where $p_{i}$ are the probability of getting number $i$.

You can solve this by using this proportion and the fact that they sum up to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

In statistics and probability, proportionality is often denoted as $\propto$. 
In our case, we have

$\mathbb{P}(k)\propto k  \ \iff \ \mathbb{P}(k)=c\cdot k,$

for $k\in \{1,2,\cdots,6\}$ and some fixed constant $c\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$.

A constant $c$ must then satisfy:

$\sum_{i=1}^{6}\mathbb{P}(i)=1  \ \Longrightarrow  \ c\cdot(\sum_{i=1}^{6}k)=1$.